# Django filter() on field of related model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I think I'm missing something very basic and fundamental about how Django's `filter()` method is supposed to work.

Using the following models:

```
class Collection(models.Model): 
    pass

class Item(models.Model):
    flag = models.BooleanField()
    collection =  models.ForeignKey(Collection)
```

and with data supplied by calling the `populate()` function at the bottom of the question, try executing the following in `./manage.py shell`:

```
len(Collection.objects.filter(item__flag=True))
```

My expectation was that this would print "2", which is the number of Collections that have at least one Item with flag=True. This expectation was based on the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships, which has an example saying "This example retrieves all Entry objects with a Blog whose name is 'Beatles Blog'".

However, the call above actually prints "6", which is the number of Item records that have `flag=True`. The actual objects returned are Collection objects, though. It seems that it's returning the same Collection object multiple times, once for each corresponding Item record with `flag=True`. This can be confirmed by:

```
queryset = Collection.objects.filter(item__flag=True)
queryset[0] == queryset[1]
```

which prints True.

Is this the correct behaviour? If so what is the rationale? If it is what is expected, the documentation could be construed as strictly correct, but it omits to say that each object can be returned multiple times.

Here is a related example, which seems to be very surprising (or just plain wrong) behaviour. It caught me out in a case where an `exclude()` call was being added by a custom model manager and the caller was then adding a `filter()`:

```
from django.db.models import Count    
[coll.count for coll in Collection.objects.filter(item__flag=True).annotate(count=Count("item"))]
[coll.count for coll in Collection.objects.exclude(item=None).filter(item__flag=True).annotate(count=Count("item"))]
```

The first case prints "[2,4]", but the second prints "[8,16]"!!!

Populate function:

```
def populate():
    Collection.objects.all().delete()

    collection = Collection()
    collection.save()
    item = Item(collection=collection, flag=True)
    item.save()
    item = Item(collection=collection, flag=True)
    item.save()
    item = Item(collection=collection, flag=False)
    item.save()
    item = Item(collection=collection, flag=False)
    item.save()

    collection = Collection()
    collection.save()
    item = Item(collection=collection, flag=True)
    item.save()
    item = Item(collection=collection, flag=True)
    item.save()
    item = Item(collection=collection, flag=True)
    item.save()
    item = Item(collection=collection, flag=True)
    item.save()

    collection = Collection()
    collection.save()
    item = Item(collection=collection, flag=False)
    item.save()
    item = Item(collection=collection, flag=False)
    item.save()
    item = Item(collection=collection, flag=False)
    item.save()
    item = Item(collection=collection, flag=False)
    item.save()
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It turns out there are two parts to this. First is the distinct() method, for which the doc says:

> By default, a QuerySet will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice,
>   this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as
>   Blog.objects.all() don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result
>   rows. However, if your query spans multiple tables, it’s possible to
>   get duplicate results when a QuerySet is evaluated. That’s when you’d
>   use distinct().

The following outputs "2" as expected:

```
len(Collection.objects.filter(item__flag=True).distinct())
```

However, this doesn't help with the more complex example I gave, using annotate(). It turns out this is an instance of a known issue: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060.